# Usando duas conexões com MongoDB usando Mongoose com referências a coleções distintas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Tenho dois bancos de dados MongoDB que conecto usando Mongoose no NodeJS, um com uma coleção X que faz referências a ID de outra coleção Y que está em outro banco de dados MongoDB em outro servidor.

Preciso unificar os dois bancos de dados copiando a coleção X conforme certos critérios para o banco que contem a coleção Y. Mantendo os dados da coleção X atualizado em ambos os servidores de bancos de dados.

Como posso transportar um Modelo de uma conexão para outra?

Comment: Você quer importar os dados de uma banco para outro ou usa-los simultaneamente?

Comment: ambos, tanto importar de forma a manter o segundo atualizado, quando usar simultaneamente, já que no banco 1 não terá as coleções Y.

Comment: Você tem dois servidores distintos? Você pode usar as ferramentas como o mongodump para salvar os documentos em um arquivo e depois importá-lo para o outro servidor usando mongorestore.

Comment: bem como eu disse na pergunta, há critérios a serem considerados. E isso será em tempo de execução.